# "MailTo" & Windows 10 Mail client in VB

Tags: vb.net, email, mailto

My VB app can send an email to myself using the following code format:

```
Process.Start("mailto:test@myself.com&subject=somesubject&body=somebodytext")
```

This works well with email clients so far except Windows 10 Mail. For Mail the entire string is saved to the "To" line. What am I missing please?

"To" line: "test@myself.com?subject=somesubject&body=somebodytext"

Also, how best to test for Mail being the email client?

Comment: This fails in a lot more ways than just the windows 10 mail client.

Comment: It should be _Process.Start("mailto:test@myself.com?subject=somesubject&body=somebodytext");_ Which email client understand correctly that syntax?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note that I had tried the "?" between the To and Subject, that format is what resulted in the example from an email I tried that I listed. And it has been working with Outlook using the "&" between the To and Subject.